# Do I need MVC in ASP.Net Core + React application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, asp.net-core

I want to develop an application with React and ASP.Net Core. The default template comes with MVC architecture. What's the point of MVC when using React with ASP.NET Core? Isn't WebAPI as backend and React as frontend a better approach?

Thank you!

Comment: No you don't need MVC. Creating a new ASP.NET core Web API project does not adds any other dependencies than Microsoft.NETCore.App

Comment: Thank you for your comment Aseem. Then, why the default project adds it? What's the best practice?

Comment: MVC and Web API got combined in Core. You can build either MVC controllers or API controllers with MVC Core.

Comment: @SherleyDev I am using VS on OSX. MVC is not added when I create a new Web API project. Perhaps this happens on windows.

Comment: It is added when using react template. (dotnet new react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @juunas commented, it's *all* MVC. More accurately, it's all "Core", but the extensions methods used to bootstrap the framework all use "MVC" in their name. If you don't need view rendering and such, it's possible you can get by with doing `services.AddMvcCore()`, instead of `services.AddMvc()`. That will reduce the service load slightly, but also may not include everything you might want to use.

If you refer to the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs), you can see that `services.AddMvc()` first calls `AddMvcCore` and then continues to also add:

```
builder.AddApiExplorer();
builder.AddAuthorization();

AddDefaultFrameworkParts(builder.PartManager);

// Order added affects options setup order

// Default framework order
builder.AddFormatterMappings();
builder.AddViews();
builder.AddRazorViewEngine();
builder.AddRazorPages();
builder.AddCacheTagHelper();

// +1 order
builder.AddDataAnnotations(); // +1 order

// +10 order
builder.AddJsonFormatters();

builder.AddCors();
```

If you don't need any of that, you can just go with `AddMvcCore` and call it a day. If you do need certain bits, you can always add those manually, i.e.:

```
services.AddMvcCore();
services.AddJsonFormatters();
services.AddCors();
// etc.
```